# OpenNTF Domino API crashes Domino Designer V10

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, domino-designer-eclipse

I tried to use the OpenNTF Domino API (ODA) Release 10.0.1. But after install, the client doesn't start anymore. Only unsinstall and new install solves that.

On my old installation with Notes 9.0.1, I could install it, but couldn't select it in the xpages-properties. Now I have updated to Notes 10.0.1 and after instaling the plugin, the client doesn't start anymore. Log shows an error: FrameworkEvent ERROR org.openntf.domino.rest

Same problem, if I try to install the OpenNTF ExtLib V17.

I would really appreciate to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The FrameworkError with org.openntf.domino.rest is expected and not an issue.

The fact that you're having issues with two different plugins suggests it's a separate issue, not related to each specific plugin. This may be the explanation, if no plugin is working https://openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=JGAR-B9QL8B.

Also, review \framework\rcp\deploy\jvm.properties to make sure you're Xms setting is sufficient https://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-notes-client-jvm-heap/. If not, startup will be slow and appear to hang. 256Mb is a good setting, in my experience. Initial load memory can go above 128Mb, max is typically below 256Mb.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But other plugins work, i.e. debug toolbar. I checked the things in the mentioned article already. I will check the heap.

Comment: I checked the heap setting in jvm.properties. It is:
vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx512m
vmarg.Xms=-Xms48m
vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca512k
Seems to be okay for me, isn't it?

Comment: I have to correct myself. It seems, that you are right and I cannot install any plugin anymore. I get a lot of warnings after plugin install like this:
CWPPR0540W: Bei der Suche nach dem Feature com.ibm.rcp.provisioning.feature auf der Updatesite file:/C%3A/Users/Vera/AppData/Local/Temp/pft950A.tmp/updateSite ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten.

And then a final error:
CWPPR0010E: Beim Bereitstellen der erforderlichen Features ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.Ursache [0]: CWPPR0032E: Die angeforderten Bereitstellungsvorgänge sind gescheitert.
I think, I have to open a support case at HCL.

Comment: It's worth ensuring you're trying to install the latest version of ODA. There were dependencies on core Domino plugins which are no longer included with Domino. So older versions of ODA won't work with 9.0.1 FP10+. Help > Support > View Trace includes more detailed logging.

Comment: With Rel. 10.0.1 FP3 it works. Sorry, that didn't see, that this fix pack already exists.

Comment: I was to early with my comment. With 10.0.1FP3 installation works, but org.openntf.domino still cannot be resolved. I had to add my local directory NotesData/workspace/applications/eclipse to the target platform in the preferences.

Comment: My workaround doesn't work properly. Factory cannot be resolved. I stop my testing now and work the old way. Maybe it will work with some new fixes, but currently ODA seems not to work with Notes 10.0.1FP3.

Comment: Needing to add NotesData/workspace/applications/eclipse is the Target Platform issue in the first link. That is a local issue and would have prevented any plugins installed via File > Application > Install.

Your mentioned FP3 after I mentioned latest version of ODA. I was referring to latest version of ODA, https://oda.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API/releases/E913D3C6221D117B852583F20047CE04. I never installed FP3, but had no problems with FP2 or D11 betas, so I'd be surprised at an FP3 issue. No one else has reported that either.

Comment: The described problem with the target is different. In my case there was a correct target set and I added an additional one.   I don't know what is different in my installation. I did a clean new install.  I tried to use it in a Java bean. Is that maybe a reason, why no one before has got problems?